# Squeeze ndarray along an axis by applying tuple() along that axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given an `ndarray` I want to squeeze it along an axis so that, elements along that dimension will form tuples, i. e. it will generate an `ndarray` of tuples having one less dimension than the parent `ndarray`.

Suppose I have a three dimensional array given below, which is basically generated by `numpy.indices` from a two dimensional array.

```
    idx = array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [2, 2, 2, 2]],

                 [[0, 1, 2, 3],
                  [0, 1, 2, 3],
                  [0, 1, 2, 3]]])
```

I tried to use `numpy.apply_along_axis` with `tuple()`.

```
numpy.apply_along_axis(tuple, 0, idx)
```

It did not work. So, created a dummy wrapper around `tuple()` and passed that function to check if `tuple()` is working as expected or not.

```
def dtuple(x):
    print(tuple(x))
    return tuple(x)
```

The output was:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]])
```

Clearly, the `tuple()` is working fine but strangely, it did not return the `ndarray` of `tuple` objects, instead it returned the same `ndarray`. I also tried passing `idx.astype(object)` instead of just `idx` but that did not work either. Note that, I am trying to avoid `for` loop here. The expected output is as follows:

```
array([[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
       [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Have you taken time to look at the code for `apply_along_axis`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try some alternatives:

```
In [563]: x=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                                                 
In [564]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda i:[12],1,x)                                                       
Out[564]: 
array([[12],
       [12],
       [12]])
In [565]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda i:(1,2,3),1,x)                                                    
Out[565]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
In [566]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda i:i,1,x)                                                          
Out[566]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [567]: np.apply_along_axis(lambda i:i*2,1,x)                                                        
Out[567]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [16, 18, 20, 22]])
```

Look at the docs:

```
out : ndarray  (Ni..., Nj..., Nk...)
    The output array. The shape of `out` is identical to the shape of
    `arr`, except along the `axis` dimension. This axis is removed, and
    replaced with new dimensions equal to the shape of the return value
    of `func1d`. So if `func1d` returns a scalar `out` will have one
    fewer dimensions than `arr`.
```

Regardless of whether the function returns a number, a list, a tuple, or an array, it still takes it as a dimension.  The dtype remains numeric.

Why are you trying to avoid a loop? `apply_along_axis` doesn't avoid a loop, it just hides it in a function.

Here's a nice loop:

```
In [578]: arr = np.empty(x.shape[0],object)                                                            
In [579]: for i,v in enumerate(x): 
     ...:     arr[i] = tuple(v.tolist()) 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [580]: arr                                                                                          
Out[580]: array([(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10, 11)], dtype=object)
```

====

With your `idx`, here's a way, via a structured array.  It's a little more convoluted than I'd like, but it's my bed time.

```
In [596]: arr = np.zeros((3,4),'i,i')                                                                  
In [597]: arr['f0']=idx[0]                                                                             
In [598]: arr['f1']=idx[1]                                                                             
In [599]: arr                                                                                          
Out[599]: 
array([[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
       [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [600]: arr.tolist()                                                                                 
Out[600]: 
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
 [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
 [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]]
In [601]: arr1=np.empty((3,4),object)                                                                  
In [602]: arr1[...] = _600                                                                             
In [603]: arr1                                                                                         
Out[603]: 
array([[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)],
       [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
       [(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing explicit loop with an assumption that the library functions are better implementation than what I would do, also they probably take advantage of broadcasting and vectorization by default. In this case the problem is the function does not return scalar. Do you think simple `for` loop with `enumerate` will perform equally well?

Comment: Some functions are just for convenience, not speed